# Do I need lvm password and passeord for my user-account

Tags: installation, password, users, lvm

Just install an new copy of Ubuntu 13.10
Now it give me the option to make an password on my lvm-volume..

But then I have to password to write, to do an full login!
My lvm-password and password for my user-accounts.

After my understanding.
I have the option to just only encrypt my user-accounts folers: /home/user
But is this encryption as strong as the one for the lvm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with the exception that someone without the key can still see the number and size of files in your home directory.